# Is there a batch script that will set the 'Allow user to change password' to false?

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp

I have created a script that when you run it, it sets the 'password will never expire' on all accounts to false so the passwords will never expire. The script is as follows:

```
WMIC USERACCOUNT WHERE "Name='administrator'" SET PasswordExpires=FALSE
```

I was wondering if there was a script that would allow me to ensure that the 'Allow user to change password box was ticked as well but I was unable to do this. I have tried the following script lines:

```
WMIC USERACCOUNT WHERE "Name='administrator'" SET PasswordChange=FALSE

WMIC USERACCOUNT WHERE "Name='administrator'" SET AllowPasswordChange=FALSE
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of searching on the net, I think you are after

```
PasswordChangeable
```

Comment: No problem, if this answered your question you should click the tick to show it as accepted :)